# What to bid for this treasure chest? (puzzle)

Tags: probability, puzzle

Suppose you are given the opportunity to bid for a treasure chest, which you know to be priced anywhere between 0-1000 dollars inclusive). Treasure price is uniformly distributed. If you bid equal to or above the price, you win the treasure chest (at the cost of your bid). If you bid below the price, you do not earn the treasure chest and get your money back. Now, also suppose you have a friend who is willing to buy the treasure chest from you for 1.5 times the price of the treasure chest (should you obtain the chest). What should your bid be?

I don't know how to approach the problem. How can I calculate expected value?

Comment: Your question is phrased as a stand-alone problem, without any further information or context. This does not match our quality standards, and hence is likely to attract downvotes, or be closed. It is impossible for us to assess your issues with the problem, and the level of answer appropriate for you. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) is a guide to asking a good question. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. This helps attract more appropriate answers and will likely remove down- and close votes.

Comment: The answer depends on the probability distribution of the treasure price. If it is uniformly distributed, a bid of $a$ will earn me a treasure of expected value $\frac a2$, which I can sell to obtain an expected value of $\frac 34a$. This is always $<a$, so I should bid as littel as possible (to minimize the loss if I win as well as the probability of a loss occuring in the first place). With other probability distributions, the answer may be different.

Comment: Corrected to include element about uniform price distribution. So should I bid $0 (i.e., not play the game)?

Comment: (commentary: I suspected that this question would garner a few upvotes, as it is seems to match the level of difficulty of many popular questions on this site. But it shows no effort or motivation, hence my votes/copypasta)

Comment: @Vuora305: you have posted 4 similar (puzzle? howework?) questions in the last hour. You should add some context or motivation.

Comment: @leonbloy: yeah, this is part of a collection of puzzles I've come across but don't have the solutions to. I'm curious of others' approach.

Answer (score 4):

If you bid $a$, the probability you win the item is $a/1000$. The expected amount you win is $(a/1000)\times (a/2)$ where $a/2$ is the mean of the value given it is less than $a$.

Then you receive $3/2$ multiplied by this as a prize. This is bounded by $3a/4$ so on average you make a loss of $\ge a/4$. Of course, there is a possibility you win something, but it's probably not large enough to make it worth it. (This is a matter of opinion, not maths.)

Comment: can you explain why it is bounded by 3a/4 on average?

Comment: $a/1000 \le 1$ for any choice of $a \le 1000$, so the mean $\mu = (a/1000) \times (a/2) \times 3/2 \le 3a/4$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good answer without making some assumption about the probability distribution of the price.  If the price were exactly $0$ it would fit the $0-1000$ range and you should not bid.  If you want to assume a uniform distribution, the problem can be solved.  Let my bid be $y$ and the price of the chest be $x$.  My gain is $$g(x,y)=\begin {cases} 0 & y \lt x \\1.5x-y & y \ge x \end {cases}$$  So for a bid $y$ the expected gain is $$\frac 1{1000}\int_0^{1000} g(x,y) dx=\frac 1{1000}\int_0^y(1.5x-y)\;dx=\frac 1{1000}\left.\left(\frac {3x^2}4-y^2\right)\right|_0^y=-\frac {y^2}{4000}$$
So I should still not bid.  The basic reason is that there is too much room from $x=0$ to $x=\frac 23y$ where I take a loss.