# Pirate Chest Bidding Question

Tags: probability

Suppose you are given the opportunity to bid for a treasure chest, which you know with 100% confidence to be priced anywhere between $0-$1000. If you bid equal to or above the price, you win the treasure chest (at the cost of your bid). If you bid below the price, you do not earn the treasure chest. Now, also suppose you have a friend who is willing to buy the treasure chest from you for one and a half times the price of the treasure chest (should you obtain the chest). What should your bid be?

I don't know how to rigorously prove its $500 either, for the first bit.

I think the answer is $500 for the first bit, but I don't know how to accomodate the friend buying it from me. Can anyone help please?

Comment: @AnCar thanks for reminding me it was from a previous question I worked out. Edited.

Comment: I am assuming that a priori the price of the chest can be anything within the price range with equal probability right? It's just as likely to cost 1 or 1000 correct? And the price will always be in fixed units? Or could it be e.g. 500.5?

Comment: yes that's right @AnCar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to bid for this treasure chest? (puzzle)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372630/what-to-bid-for-this-treasure-chest-puzzle)

Comment: As @Sungjin-woo pointed out, that should answer your question if you meant that if you bid and don't get the chest you get your money back. If your bid money is lost regardless of winning the chest or not and if you bid $x$, you will expect to lose $x(\frac{3}{4000}x-1)$ (similar proof), so again the correct strategy is to bid $0$. Regarding the no friend to pay up $1.5$ times situation, that is equivalent to the friend just paying you the value of the chest, so the strategy is again to not bid.

Comment: In summary, whatever your bid $(B)$, if your bid succeeds, then the expected value of the treasure chest is $(B/2)$.